# How to pass column name in R to function as an argument for nested function

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, spread

I see a lot of questions on that but nothing works in my particular case.
I am building function which pivots certain columns long to wide. It spreads factors so they can be transformed to integers (flags). Inside I use function `spread()` that takes name of the column to be spread. I tried all the combinations I can find and nothing works. This function is going to be reusable and pivot various columns in one pass. So passing column names is essential.

This is one of many not working tricks I tried: `key = dataFrame[, columnName]` inside of `spread()`. (last line of the function body)

Here is the function code:

```
pivotColumn <- function(dataFrame, columnName) {

as.data.frame(dataFrame %>% 
group_by_( .dots = names(dataFrame)[1:ncol(dataFrame)] ) %>% 
tally %>% dplyr::rename(temporary = n) %>% 
spread( key = dataFrame[, columnName], value = "temporary", fill = ""))

}
```

If someone wants to use this function, a dummy column needs to be added with unique values otherwise some observations will be removed as duplicates.  After operation the column can be removed.(I do it at the beginning of cleaning and remove at the end).

Comment: For clarity abbreviated version of this function would look like this:

     `pivotColumn <- function(df, colname) {
      spread(df,  key = dataFrame[, colname], value = "temporary")
     }`